Partition positive integers into finite collection of sets
Is it possible to partition the positive integers into a finite collection of sets {$S_{i}$} such that
$$j,k \in S_{i}, j \ne k \implies j+k \notin S_{i}$$
My suspicion is that this is not possible, but I have so far not been able to prove it.
My attempts so far have been given a partition of n sets, put 1,..,n in different partitions, then put n+1 in the first partition, n+2, n+3 in the second partition, put n+4, n+5, n+6 in the third partition etc… However continuing this way, you run into the problem that the sum of the last 2 numbers in a partition are (eventually) greater or equal then the number. So, you need to put the number in a different partition, and for small number of partitions you eventually run into the situation where any partition you put a number into is invalid.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Are $j$ and $k$ distinct?

@BobDobbs The answer is no in either case.

Do you know Ramsey's theorem?

Thanks! Sorry, I did mean j,k are distinct. I will look up Ramsey’s theorem. Was not aware of it.
@JoséCarlosSantos I just had a natural curiosity about it. So not really any context, but put in my attempt to solve it so far.
